# Find Routes within Range of a Point

Tags: mysql, google-maps, routes, geospatial, polyline

I am seeking a way using Google Maps to take a predefined latlng point and find routes that pass within 20 miles. The start and end points for the route exist in a MySQL DB.

1. Would it be best, when storing the routes, to include all the polylines that make up the route?
2. Should I store the RouteBoxer coordinates and find all boxes that contain the predefined latlng point? This may be up to 3x greater distance then 20 miles
3. How should I store the data for both predefined latlng points and the route information?

**EDIT:**

This article may bring some ideas but I am still unsure of the best method? I am concerned with scaling because I am thinking of 50,000+ routes and thousands of routes.

--> [Find how many (googlemap) polygons near x distance of a point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461295/find-how-many-googlemap-polygons-near-x-distance-of-a-point?rq=1)

--> [Get polygons close to a lat,long in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902287/get-polygons-close-to-a-lat-long-in-mysql)

--> [MySQL Find Polygon Nearest to Point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879337/mysql-find-polygon-nearest-to-point)

Thanks very much!

David

Comment: Hope it helps... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586708/get-results-that-fall-within-marker-radiuses-from-database